# how to get "foo" from URL: http://www.loremipsum.com/mysite.html#foo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

is there a way in javascript (jQuery) or PHP to get something after `.html` ?

I've tried in PHP `$_SERVER['request_uri']` and JS `window.location.pathname;`

But it seems that everything is stripped away after `.html`

Anyone an idea how I could submit `#foo` after `.html`?

Comment: GET does not work in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For javascript try this

```
hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

But pay attantion this will not work in IE 7.

If you want to support IE7

```
hash = window.location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf("#"));
```

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript you can get it using `hash` property:

```
window.location.hash
```

Comment: that gets #foo not foo

Comment: @Sam but due to OP question this is what he want: "Anyone an idea how I could submit #foo after .html?"

Comment: I stand corrected, I hadn't noticed he'd asked that last sentence different to the question. Voted your answer up

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

in Javascript:

```
var query = location.href.split('#');
console.log(query[1]);
```

in PHP, You can use [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/parse_url) if you supplied the mentioned full url , Since you have added `php` tag

```
$url="http://www.loremipsum.com/mysite.html#foo";
$urls = parse_url($url);        
$fragment = $urls['fragment'];
```

Comment: I would like a PHP way, but I need to get the url from the browser. and that's where "#foo" gets lost.

Comment: The example given above works perfectly

Comment: @Grant how will it work if I need something like $url=$_SERVER['request_uri']; if "#foo" is nowhere in a var_dump($_SERVER)?

Comment: $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; Obviously the URL must contain #foo at the end.

Comment: @Grant ok I wrote "request_uri" not in uppercase. but it want work. try it...

Comment: $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    
    $urls = parse_url($url);
    
    $fragment = $urls['fragment'];
    
    echo $fragment; Then run the file from your browswer appending #foo after the file name

Answer (score 0):

It makes it totally different whether you need to get is in the client [js] or in the server [php].

In the client, you just access it via `window.location.hash`.

In the server, mind that the fragment are never sent across HTTP, so you have to send it either as a querystring, or in the request body [if the HTTP method allows it].

Comment: could you please explain how could I send it with querystring or in the request body? How do I see if HTTP method allows it?

Comment: @caramba you should depict your goal and you scenario. Answering the second question, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) is relevant enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location.hash instead of window.location.pathname.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
<?php  
$pageURL = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";

if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80"){
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $urls = parse_url($pageURL);        
    $fragment = $urls['fragment'];
    echo $fragment; //foo
} else {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $urls = parse_url($pageURL);        
    $fragment = $urls['fragment'];
    echo $fragment; //foo
}
?>
```